# Export list of TinyCA2 certificates

Tags: vpn

How can I export a list of TinyCA2 certificates held on a machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it... on Ubuntu machines it's in

```
/var/vpn/TinyCA/[some_name]/index.txt
```